# Magento 1.9 - .htaccess file missing

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess

I have a problem with the `.htaccess` file in the root category of my server. It is not there.
I searched for hours (google), but i haven't found any solutions. **(Magento 1.9)**

I activated **"display hidden files" in Filezilla** (I'm not working with APACHE - I'm working with a Testdomain), but it is still lost...

I need the .htaccess file for setting up Multilingual Websites on my Server.

The only .htaccess file I Found is the one in the `var` folder:

```
Order deny,allow Deny from all
```

Thanks.!

Comment: Just copy one htaccess file from a clean instance

Comment: I think I solved it. I uploaded a Template with Quickstart. I extracted the "quickstart-template" file with my macbook...htaccess didn't appeare. Then I extacted it with another computer... htaccsess appeared... "That seems strange to me."

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried uploading a new version / copy from your original Magento 1.9 download?

If you don't have this then grab another version via http://www.magentocommerce.com/download and see if that works.

Comment: You mean I should download Magento 1.9 again and upload it to my server?

Comment: No, you merely have to download the appropriate version .zip/.bzip/.gz file and dearchive it on your local workstation. All the files are there including the stock .htaccess file. Upload just that file to the server. Also is quite handy if you're experimenting and forgot to save a copy of any .phtml or .php file Magento uses before perpetrating mayhem <grin>.

Comment: I uploaed the .htaccess file, but now Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: This may have been caused by mismatched line ending formats between Linux / OSX / Windows or incorrect chmod permissions being applied to the file after extraction.  @FiascoLabs suggestion was ideal because it should guarantee that you get a trusted copy from the authoritative source, Magento, and be sure it hasn't been modified or introduces vulnerabilities into your system that could be exploited later.  The line ending issue is [well-documented](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types) and you'll see it over and again working on the web

Answer (score 2):

For me, it is just Hidden/Invisible. You should try click the the option display Hidden/Invisible file (depend on host) when open your File Manager.

Answer (score 2):

try to login with ssh in Ubuntu terminal and use ls -all command you can also edit this file.

Answer (score 2):

Stock 1.9 .htaccess

```
############################################
## uncomment these lines for CGI mode
## make sure to specify the correct cgi php binary file name
## it might be /cgi-bin/php-cgi

#    Action php5-cgi /cgi-bin/php5-cgi
#    AddHandler php5-cgi .php

############################################
## GoDaddy specific options

#   Options -MultiViews

## you might also need to add this line to php.ini
##     cgi.fix_pathinfo = 1
## if it still doesn't work, rename php.ini to php5.ini

############################################
## this line is specific for 1and1 hosting

    #AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
    #AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

############################################
## default index file

    DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>

############################################
## adjust memory limit

#    php_value memory_limit 64M
    php_value memory_limit 256M
    php_value max_execution_time 18000

############################################
## disable magic quotes for php request vars

    php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off

############################################
## disable automatic session start
## before autoload was initialized

    php_flag session.auto_start off

############################################
## enable resulting html compression

    #php_flag zlib.output_compression on

###########################################
# disable user agent verification to not break multiple image upload

    php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off

###########################################
# turn off compatibility with PHP4 when dealing with objects

    php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
###########################################
# disable POST processing to not break multiple image upload

    SecFilterEngine Off
    SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip

    # Insert filter on all content
    ###SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    # Insert filter on selected content types only
    #AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css text/javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    #BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    #BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    #SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    #Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>

############################################
## make HTTPS env vars available for CGI mode

    SSLOptions StdEnvVars

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

############################################
## enable rewrites

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

############################################
## you can put here your magento root folder
## path relative to web root

    #RewriteBase /magento/

############################################
## uncomment next line to enable light API calls processing

#    RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]

############################################
## rewrite API2 calls to api.php (by now it is REST only)

    RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]

############################################
## workaround for HTTP authorization
## in CGI environment

    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

############################################
## TRACE and TRACK HTTP methods disabled to prevent XSS attacks

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
    RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]

<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>

        ############################################
        # X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff disable content-type sniffing on some browsers.
        Header set X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

        ############################################
        # This header forces to enables the Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter in browsers (if disabled)
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE\s8 ie8
        Header set X-XSS-Protection: "1; mode=block" env=!ie8

    </IfModule>
</IfModule>

############################################
## redirect for mobile user agents

    #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/mobiledirectoryhere/.*$
    #RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    #RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /mobiledirectoryhere/ [L,R=302]

############################################
## always send 404 on missing files in these folders

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

############################################
## never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

############################################
## rewrite everything else to index.php

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>


############################################
## Prevent character encoding issues from server overrides
## If you still have problems, use the second line instead

    AddDefaultCharset Off
    #AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

<IfModule mod_expires.c>

############################################
## Add default Expires header
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires

    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"

</IfModule>

############################################
## By default allow all access

    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

###########################################
## Deny access to release notes to prevent disclosure of the installed Magento version

    <Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
        order allow,deny
        deny from all
    </Files>

############################################
## If running in cluster environment, uncomment this
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags

    #FileETag none

###########################################
## Deny access to cron.php
    <Files cron.php>

############################################
## uncomment next lines to enable cron access with base HTTP authorization
## http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html
##
## Warning: .htpasswd file should be placed somewhere not accessible from the web.
## This is so that folks cannot download the password file.
## For example, if your documents are served out of /usr/local/apache/htdocs
## you might want to put the password file(s) in /usr/local/apache/.

        #AuthName "Cron auth"
        #AuthUserFile ../.htpasswd
        #AuthType basic
        #Require valid-user

############################################

        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all

    </Files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download original htaccess file from http://www.magentocommerce.com/download. After downloading the Magento package you need, exact and get .htaccess file in the package.

In addition, you can also do some tweaks with your htaccess file to improve Magento website performance (reference source: [Speed magento with htaccess file](http://magentoexplorer.com/how-to-speed-up-your-site-with-magento-htaccess-file)):

**Enable Gzip Compression For Magento**

Uncomment this line

```
#php_flag zlib.output_compression on
```

**Compressing CSS and JavaScript files**

Add these lines to htaccess

```
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
</IfModule>
```

**Enable Expires Headers**

```
############################################
## Add Expires header to Magento - by Magentoexplorer.com
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#expires
    <FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
```

**Disable ETags**

```
############################################
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#etags
    FileETag none
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my blog on .htaccess file in Magento.
http://blog.rahuldadhich.com/magento-speed-optimization-htaccess/

Hope this will help you.